# What is the time complexity of following code?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

```
int count = 0;
    for (int i = N; i > 0; i /= 2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
```

I am not getting the right answer. My answer is O(NlogN) but right answer is O(N). can someone help me out?

Comment: If we assume that N is a power of 2, then the inner loop is executed with N, N/2,N/4,... That means that the overall runtime is N * ( 1 +1/2 + 1/4 + ...). And that is a geometric series which converges to 2*N.

Comment: What about first loop which decreasing the value of i by half times?

Comment: You might plot the values for different values of N to convince yourself.

Comment: What do you think how many iterations have the inner loop n the first iteration of the outer one? And how many on the secons, third ...? The answer will lead you to sum in my answer above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 ... ~= 2 right?

So you go through each elements less than 2n times which is O(N)

Comment: What about first loop which decreasing the value of i by half times?

Comment: You are correct I think that you go through the first loop log(N) times, but every time you go through the first loop the second loop is half as long. If the condition was "j < N" then it would be O(N log N)